# Trying to create a user account from a new entity

Tags: jhipster

First of all i'm new to Jhipster, i've read the official documentations but i still can't seem to find a solution to my problem (i've been stuck for almost 3 weeks now), that's why i decided to ask here for help.

So, i have an application where i need to create an entity called employee and i need to create a user account with the additional fields taht are specified in the employee entity, so in other words, when i fill the form to create a new employee that will not only create a new one but it will also automatically create a user account for that emplyee.

What i've tried doing up until now, is creating a new employee entity and link it with a OneToOne relashionship to the USER entity (created by Jhipster) but the thing is, in that case i would have to create a new user and then add the additional information for the employee, wheareas i need it to be in the same form, to create an employee and the user linked to it at the same time.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not supported off the shelf by JHipster, you have to code it manually.

In backend, you could do it by defining a DTO that combines both entities, a RestController that exposes it and a service that is responsible for orchestrating persistence.

In frontend, it's the same you have a component that contains the form to update this DTO and call your REST API.

Alternatively, if a User is always an Employee, you could also merge them in a single User entity.

Of course, this depends on which authentication type you selected which defines where users are managed.